# How to access local JSON file of given format on web page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax

**Where am I going wrong?**
I am not able to access JSON file on web page so please check all my related codes.

**index.html**

```
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Kota</a>
    <a href class="floatingbox list" 
       ng-repeat="nav in navs"></a>
       <a href ng-repeat="n in nav.data_list">{{n.name}}</a>

    <a href="#" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**data.json file**

```
 {
    "view_type": 2,
    "position": 2,
    "data_list": [
        {
            "name": "Merchant",
            "img": "url"
        },
        {
            "name": "Hostel & PG",
            "img": "url"
        },
        {
            "name": "Education",
            "img": "url"
        }
```

**app.js**

```
function NavController($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.navs = data;
    });
```

Comment: Access, or display? Your `<a>` tag is closed after the first `ng-repeat`, so the second one can't access `nav`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data.json').
  then(function(response) {
      $scope.nav = response.data;
  });
});
```

[WORKING PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/gmUcUdGXrQwMJVY2f9qp?p=preview)

Comment: Can you tell me how to access the images from this JSON file on the web page? What will be the code for this in app.js and index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor tag was not closing properly.

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Kota</a>
    <a href class="floatingbox list" 
       ng-repeat="nav in navs">
       <a href ng-repeat="n in nav.data_list">{{n.name}}</a>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And also you need to add app controller in order to invoke the `$http` methods

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data.json').
  then(function(response) {
      $scope.nav = response.data;
  });
});
```